# Inspect and test multiple live URLs in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, url

Is it possible to live test multiple URLs instead of manually submit each url and click the "live test" button in the Google Search Console -> URL Inspection tool?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Currently this feature is not in the new Google Search Console. Although we are expecting that it will be available soon.

Comment: Hello, any udpate on this question ? thanks !

Comment: Hi, it has been 3 years since this question was first asked, and I still can not inspect multiple URL's... Is there any roadmap to do this in the future? This is making my life unbearable right now. I have to manually check hundreds of pages where I have to wait 2 minutes in-between. Which means I'd have to do manual labor for tens of hours just because there isn't a select all of these previously non indexed url's... This can literally cause people to get Repetitive Strain Injuries. And I am not in the mood of writing automation software because someone decided not to implement a checkbox...